# Do lower tier papers reduce the value of a PhD Applicant? (CS PhD USA FALL 2022)

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate

I have a 5 page paper "technically published" (No online doi, just a certificate and a best paper award) at a conference which was organised by my university. The paper is broadly focused on my domain but it is something I do no work on anymore.

I will not be mentioning it in my SOP. My letter writers won't be mentioning it either.

**Question:**

1. Will this add any value to my profile for CS PhD Admissions? (USA)
2. Will it in any way hamper my profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly fine and very consistent with your state of education. It is a good thing to show and illustrate your accomplishments!

However, keep in mind: this changes with time.

While it is 100% ok to highlight low-tier accomplishment (non-peer reviewed publications, publications on topic you have only worked on in an early and very short time, student work, etc.), or even plans ("planned to be published") in early stages of your research,  in the following steps of your career you should always carefully review those. If you have at some point excellent quality peer-reviewed paper then remove those early accomplishments.

This basically correlates with how far you mastered to become a truly independent and original self-thinking scholar. Thus, this transition in time is quite flexible and typically happens roughly within your time as a PhD.

It is never a bad thing to be concise and to-the-point, in particular also in applications. It is not the goal to deliver bloat that even hides your true accomplishments.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks. In this case also accept the answer. Thanks again.